# Connect To the MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table on PHPmyamdmin, and when i try to select it with the following code:

```
 *<?php
    //connect.php
     session_start();
    $server = 'localhost';
    $username   = 'zimmer';
    $password   = '';
    $database   = 'csgopit';

    if(!mysql_connect($server, $username))
    {  
      exit('Error: could not establish database connection');
    }
    if(!mysql_select_db($database))
    {   
     exit('Error: could not select the database');
     }
    ?>*
```

i get this error when i open the page in localhost:

> Error: could not select the database

In the database i have 4 tables, one of them is users and i have manually added the user "zimmer" to it, i'm using this to create and experiment forum in my learning experiences, also, using this same code as a "connect.php" if i use it as for example on another file simply by using this line

```
using connect.php or include connect.php
```

would it work in a login or would it load only the user zimmer?
I started with PHP couple of days ago so sorry for the rookie question.

Comment: Nitpick: you don't have a table in phpmyadmin. You have a table in MySQL, for which phpmyadmin is a management interface.

Comment: Stop using depricated `mysql_`API. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO. call `mysql_error` to see what the problem is

Comment: @Marc B yes sorry, i have an SQL table in PHPmyAdmin

Comment: @Jens using mysqli_error i get this message: Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Your code uses `mysql_connect()`, not `mysqli`, so calling `mysqli_error()` is not going to be helpful. You need `echo mysql_error();` inside error block for `mysql_select_db()`.  It will likely be either that the database does not exist as specified in `$database`, or that the connected user lacks permission to use it.

Comment: But the earlier recommendation not to use `mysql_*()` stands. It is a deprecated extension that will be removed in a soon-to-be-released PHP version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try PDO.

```
$handler = '';
$server = 'localhost';
$username = 'zimmer';
$password = '';
$database = 'csgopit';

try {
    $this->handler = new PDO('mysql:host='. $server .';dbname='. $database . ';charset=utf8', $username, $password);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

But you also mentioned you added the user "zimmer" to the users table. This is different than your $username you pass to connect to the database.

Did you set up a username and password to a database?

Comment: Hi chad, thank you! The problem was that i was not using the correct user name, i was unaware that i needed to use the PHPMYADMIN account, i'm new to the platform so it was a rookie mistake, however PDO looks good aswell, i'm gonna go ahead and try it out aswell.

Comment: Yea, NP. There is plenty on PDO out there - how to connect, query, etc. It's more of a modern, OO way of coding database queries. Good luck!

Comment: @LesterNotTheMolestor there is no such thing as a phpMyAdmin account, you mean a MySQL account.